# SQL query - find parent posts where no children posts exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT 
count(tblReplies.repDate) as comReplies,
tblReplies.repDate
FROM tblReplies, tblQuestions, tblUsers
WHERE
tblQuestions.queID = tblReplies.repQuestionID 
AND tblQuestions.queCompanyID = tblUsers.uCompanyID
AND tblUsers.uID = tblReplies.repUserID 
AND tblUsers.uCompanyID = $comID 
AND tblQuestions.queID = $queID 
GROUP BY tblReplies.repID 
ORDER BY tblReplies.repDate ASC
```

Now, I'm trying to modify the query to find the posts in tblQuestions (queID) where there are no replies (questions that have no children in the database tblReplies). Anyone have an idea, I'm totally lost, hope there is a ninja out there :)

Thank you,

Comment: This is little more than a LEFT or right join.  Consider the following link http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html Now ask: if you query from questions left join to replies where replies.quesitonID is null you'd have all questions wihtout a reply.

Comment: Thank you for the link xQbert, now I understand the concept. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select q.*
from tblQuestions q 
left outer join tblReplies r on q.queID = r.repQuestionID
where r.repQuestionID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en//exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT q.* 
FROM   tblquestions q
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   tblreplies r
                   WHERE  r.repquestionid = q.queid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! I tried modifying the query, trying to use WHERE NOT. The idea with the query is to find all questions without replies. This is how the updated query looks, but this query only gives me empty rows, and doesn't give me the empty question IDs: SELECT 
   tblQuestions.queID
  FROM 
   tblReplies, 
   tblQuestions 
  WHERE
   tblQuestions.queID = tblReplies.repQuestionID AND
  NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT tblReplies.repID FROM tblReplies 
       WHERE tblReplies.repQuestionID = tblQuestions.queID)
  GROUP BY tblQuestions.queID